# How to simultaneously run two RealVNC servers from two users in Ubuntu?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I have installed Ubuntu Unity 22.10 on a cluster.
There are two users who want to use this computer simultaneously (both users want to remotely access the GUI). I am planning to use RealVNC to achieve that.

However, when one switches user, VNC server keeps running in the background, and it streams the screen of the other user.

How to create two VNC Server instances in the two user accounts (running simultaneously)?

---

Otherwise, is there any way to achieve this without VNC? I read about multiseat, but it seems to require a video card with two monitor outputs (I want virtual sessions).

To be more precise, user A wants to use the computer with a real monitor, and also wants to access its GUI remotely, and user B wants to access the GUI remotely. They have separate user accounts.

---

I tried creating a new graphical session from TTY, but it [did not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438787/how-to-start-a-new-x-session-from-virtual-terminal-in-ubuntu-unity).

Comment: What about XRDP?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292694/multi-user-remote-desktop-from-windows-to-linux-machine

Comment: @Terrance I did not know about XRDP. I will check it out. In RealVNC, I could login to my user account and access from anywhere (even from a different network). With XRDP, I will probably have to connect to the specific IP address. But I will definitely check it out.

Comment: @Terrance Does XRDP work with Unity?

Comment: Unfortunately, none of my systems have Unity so I can't test it out.  As far as my connections go, I have put a OpenVPN server on mine so all protocols work from anywhere.

Comment: Do you need to enable port forwarding in your router for an OpenVPN server? I don't have access to my university's routers, so I cannot enable port forwarding. Also, is there any tutorial for setting up OpenVPN server, so that all protocols (SSH/VNC/XRDP) will work from anywhere?

Comment: My VPN is on port 1194, and that is the only port other than the standard ones I opened on my router.  I also only use UDP on it and not TCP.   As far as the instructions I followed on my server I used the Pihole instructions https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/vpn/openvpn/setup-openvpn-server/  and I did have to make a couple of changes so my network would push correctly to the client system.  I had to add in my DNS and router IPs to be pushed to the client on two separate lines that were like `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.1"`.